# Changing the address of an element in a char* array? C

Tags: c, arrays

Code first:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void test (char* word)
{
    char y[20] = "hlajwoma";
    word = &y;
}


int main()
{
    char* words[3] = {NULL};

    test(words[1]);
    words[0] = "LOL0";
    words[1] = "LOL1";
    words[2] = "LOL2";

    printf("%s\n%s\n%s", words[0], words[1], words[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

So what i want to do here, is you can see that i have an array of char* called words. This array stores the memory address of the elements. I choose words[1] to be edited, but it doesn't work.

Can you point me to some directions please?

Comment: How do you expect anything to be modified if you modify **prior to** the initial assignments (to `"LOL0"`, `"LOL1"`, and `"LOL2"`)? Also note that C copies arguments by value, so `word = &y;` does effectively nothing.

Comment: `char *` is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: C is strictly pass-by--value. Aven if you pass a `char **`, you invoke undefined behaviour for returning a pointer to an automatic variable.

Comment: So I struggled with how to explain it and clarify it and have made way too many updates to my answer and may have confused you. I think it's somewhat passable now, or may give you enough clues to put together to get more of an idea of how to use C to do that kind of thing. I'm going to stop editing it and move on, so if you have some time again, give it a fresh look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*One* problem you have is that arguments are passed *by value*, basically meaning that they are copied into local variables in the function. Changing a copy will of course not change the original, and also local variables goes out of scope and cease to exist once the function returns. You usually solve it by using *pass by reference*, which doesn't exist in C but can be emulated with pointers. So you need to pass a pointer to the pointer as the argument, and use dereferencing in the function to change the value.

***However*** that leads us back to the whole "local variable" thing, and how they cease to exist once they go out of scope. Since you want to make the pointer point to the local array `y` that pointer will no longer be valid once the function returns and using the pointer will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The actual problem is that you call your function doing the "modification" *before* you do the assignment. Once you fixed the above problems you should probably change the order you do things.

Answer (score 1):

You are reassigning to `words[0]` *after* the function call. So, whatever it's supposed to modify, wouldn't work.

However, your "modification" isn't correct to start with.

With this statement

```
word = &y;
```

you are modifying a pointer `word` that's local to `test()` function. If you want to modify the content, you can use `strcpy()`. However, what you pass to `test()` is an address of a *string literal* which can't be modified.

In order to modify the pointer, you have to pass a pointer to pointer. But you can't assign the address of a *local variable* to it (which would lead to undefined behaviour).

What you probably want to do is something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void test (char **word)
{
    char *y = "hlajwoma";
    *word = y;
}


int main(void)
{
    char* words[3] = {NULL};

    words[0] = "LOL0";
    words[1] = "LOL1";
    words[2] = "LOL2";

    test(&words[0]);

    printf("%s\n%s\n%s", words[0], words[1], words[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

This

```
char *y = "hlajwoma";
```

assigns the address of the string literal `"hlajwoma"`, which has *static storage duration*, to `y`.

This is totally different from:

```
char y[] = "hlajwoma";
```

in which the string literal is *copied* into the array `y`. Thus array `y` is local to the function `test()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
words[1] = "LOL1";
```

Is a char pointer to a constant string.

Comment: And this means what? It's hard to tell what you're trying to say. (That's called string literal, not a "constant string" BTW.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want your function to be able to modify the array `words`. In other words, I take that you expect the output to be the following:

> LOL0
>   hlajwoma
>   LOL

If that's the case, then what you want is your function to receive a pointer to the array, and use this pointer to make the second element point to another string.

However, you'll run into a second problem, which is trying to make the pointer in `main` point to a string that only exists during the lifetime of `test()`. That is, when you have a code like this:

```
void test (char** word)
{
    char y[20] = "hlajwoma";
    *word = y;
}
```

The variable `y` is created by the program in the dynamic memory region when `test()` is called. When it finishes running, that string no longer exists. And if you stored its address in any pointer, that pointer now is invalid. You can simply make it point to a string literal, which exists during the whole time your program is running.

**Another** problem with your code is that you are calling `test()` first and then modifying the array. Even if `test()` works perfectly, whatever it do is being undone. So we change the order of that as well.

So you can simply do this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void test (char** word)
{
    word = "hlajwoma";
}

int main(void)
{
    char* words[3] = {NULL};

    words[0] = "LOL0";
    words[1] = "LOL1";
    words[2] = "LOL2";

    test(&words[1]);

    printf("%s\n%s\n%s", words[0], words[1], words[2]);

    return 0;
}
```